# MOSFET Inverter

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I'm trying to do some exercises to understand the functions of MOSFET transistors.

I'm doing one of them, but I can't finish it.

EDIT: Here is the problem:

The information of the problem is in itself.

TRANSLATION: In the circuit shown in Figure P3.10, with the indicated input voltages, determine and express the output voltages.
V<sub>DD</sub> = 9V; V<sub>1</sub> = 6V; V<sub>T1</sub> = V<sub>T2</sub> = 3V; β<sub>1</sub> = 0.04mA/V<sup>2</sup>; β<sub>2</sub> = 0.2mA/V<sup>2</sup>.

Answers: v<sub>i</sub>(t) = 0, v<sub>o</sub>(t) = 6V, v<sub>o</sub>(t) = 1V.

[image: Problem]

Comment: I've done the problem with Vi = 0 V, and I obtained M2 is OFF, and M1 is SAT, and the output is Vo = 6 V

Comment: Then, I've tried to do it with Vi = 6 V, but I don't know how to continue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward if we regard the use of \$\beta\$. I assume that at this point in your material you have been given the formula for DC drain current in the linear region:

\$I_{DS} = \beta\left((V_{GS}-V_T)V_{DS} - \frac{V^2_{DS}}{2}\right)\$

And for saturation region:

\$I_{DS} = \beta\frac{(V_{GS} - V_T)^2}{2}\$

Where saturation is defined as \$|V_{DS}| \geq V_{GS} - V_T\$

So let's look at the situation where \$v_i = 6V\$. Because for \$M_1\$, \$V_{GS} = V_{DS}\$, the transistor always operates in saturated mode, as long as \$V_{DS} > V_T\$. Because at \$v_i = 6V\$, \$M_2\$ is obviously on, this will be the case so we can safely assume that \$V_{DS} > V_T\$.

Now we can do two things: either try to simultaneously solve the drain current equations assuming M2 is either saturated or linear, or we can intuitively look at the problem. Let's try the last one. The transition point between linear and saturation for \$M_2\$ is \$V_{DS}=3V\$, above which we have saturation, below which the transistor operates in the linear region. At this operating point, the current through $\M_2\$ is

\$\begin{eqnarray}
I_{DS} &=& \beta\frac{(V_{GS} - V_T)^2}{2}\\
&=& 0.2 \frac{(6 - 3)^2}{2}\\
&=& 0.2 \cdot \frac{9}{2}\\
&=& 0.9mA
\end{eqnarray}\$

For \$M_1\$:

\$\begin{eqnarray}
I_{DS} &=& \beta\frac{(V_{GS} - V_T)^2}{2}\\
&=& 0.04 \frac{(6 - 3)^2}{2}\\
&=& 0.04 \cdot \frac{9}{2}\\
&=& 0.18mA
\end{eqnarray}\$

This is clearly untrue, as there is no load on \$v_o\$, the current through both transistors should be equal. Increasing \$V_{DS}\$ on \$M_2\$ won't help either, because that will only decrease drain current in \$M_1\$ while keeping drain current equal in \$M_2\$. Intuitively it should be clear that the only way to equalize these equations is for \$M_2\$ to be in the linear region and reduce the drain current this way.

So now it's easy. Solve:

\$\begin{eqnarray}
I_{DS,1,sat} &=& I_{DS,2,lin}\\
\beta_1 \frac{(V_{GS,1} - V_T)^2}{2} &=& \beta_2 \left((V_{GS,2}-V_T)V_{DS} - \frac{V^2_{DS}}{2}\right)\\
\beta_1 \frac{((9 - v_o) - 3)^2}{2} &=& \beta_2 \left((6-3)v_o - \frac{v^2_o}{2}\right)\\
\beta_1 \frac{(6 - v_o)^2}{2} &=& \beta_2 \left(3v_o - \frac{v^2_o}{2}\right)\\
18 - 6v_o + \frac{v_o^2}{2} &=& \frac{\beta_2}{\beta_1} \left(3v_o - \frac{v^2_o}{2}\right)\\
18 - 21v_o + 3v_o^2 &=& 0\\
\end{eqnarray}\$

This has solutions \$v_o = 6V | v_o = 1V\$. We know that the equations do not hold for \$v_o=6V\$, both because \$M_2\$ would then be in saturation and because the drain current in \$M_1\$ would be zero, so the answer is \$v_o = 1V\$.

And darnit, I've done it again. I swore I wouldn't do any more of these equation-heavy answers because they take a ginormous amount of time to type up. I cannot help myself.

Comment: I don't understand this step:

\$M_1\$:
$$
I_{DS} = \beta \frac{V_{GS} - V_T}{2}^2 = 0.04 \frac{6 - 3}{2}^2

Why is \$V_{GS} = 6\$?

Comment: Sorry, and I don't understand why the point of transition is \$ V_{DS} = 3 \$